# Why isn't the derivative of $a^x$ written as $xa^{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Why isn't the derivative of $a^x$ written as $xa^{x-1}$?

Why isn't the derivative of $$a^x$$ written as $$xa^{x-1}$$Just like the way using the general formula?
 Also, could anyone please show how to find derivarive in such cases?

Comment: Why would it? You are implying the rule of taking a derivative of a polynomial term on an exponential term. Doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: The derivative of $x^a$ can be written as $ax^{a-1}$ (here $x$ is variable and $a$ is constant). The functions $x\mapsto x^a$ and $x\mapsto a^x$ are quite different.

Comment: You should also specify with respect to which variable you are deriving: if the variable is $a$, that is precisely the first derivative. If the variable is $x$, as already noticed, the functions $f(x)=x^a$ and $g(x)=a^x$ are different.

Comment: So what you are thinking about is the comparison to $f(x) = x^n$, which indeed has the derivative $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$. Now, you want to compare this to $g(x) = a^x$. I would recommend plotting these two functions, and varying the parameters $n$ and $a$. You will see that these two are quite differently behaving functions ...

Answer (score 6):

We have $$\frac{d}{d\color{red}x} \color{red}x^a=ax^{a-1}$$ (note the the differentiation is with respect to $x,$ so $a$ is constant.)

This does **not** imply $$\frac{d}{d\color{red}x}a^\color{red}x=xa^{x-1}$$ because the differentiation is now with respect to the power. However, it does imply $$\frac{d}{da}a^\color{red}x=xa^{x-1}$$ since here $x$ is now the constant and $a$ is the variable of differentiation.

This is a good example to learn that the **variable of differentiation** is important.

**Edit:** Let $y = a^x.$ Then $\ln y=x \ln a.$ By chain rule $$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\ln a$$ (since $\ln a$ is a constant, so we use $\dfrac{d(cx)}{dx}=c$). Hence $$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=\frac{dy}{dx}=y\ln a=a^x\ln a.$$

Comment: However, could you please show how to go about finding the derivative of $a^x$?

Comment: @uddhavsaikia I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's because $a$ is a constant and you are probably differentiating with respect to $x$ so you don't get $xa^{x-1}$. If you differentiate with respect to a then you get $xa^{x-1}$. The difference between the derivative with respect to $x$ of the functions $f(x)=a^x$ and $g(x)=x^a$ are very obvious. The key realisation in your problem is to recognize which letters represent variables and which represent constants, and what you are differentiating with respect to.
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}a^x=\ln(a)a^x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}x^a=ax^{a-1}$$

Comment: Hey, are you part of the website 'mathsisfun'? I am currently using that!

Comment: no not really it's just that i think maths is fun

Answer (score 0):

Summary: $ \frac{d}{dx} x^a = a x^{a-1} \text{ and } \frac{d}{dx} a^x =  a^x (\ln a)$.

Here's how I remember that $\frac{d}{dx} a^x =  a^x (\ln a)$, using that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ and the chain rule. We can write $a^x$ in terms of base $e$ using that $a = e^{\ln a}$:
$$a^x = (e^{\ln a})^x = e^{(\ln a)x} .$$
Now we use the chain rule to take the derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx} a^x = \frac{d}{dx} e^{(\ln a)x} = e^{(\ln a)x} \frac{d}{dx} [(\ln a)x] = e^{(\ln a)x} (\ln a) = a^x (\ln a).$$
I'll emphasize that *power functions* ("$x$ to a constant power") and *exponential functions* ("$x$ in the exponent") are different. The derivative of a power function is a *simpler* power function (the power goes down by one), whereas the derivative of an exponential function is the *same* exponential function, times the constant $\ln a$. $e^x$ is the special exponential function whose derivative is exactly *itself*.